# How to customize ListViewItem properly with hideable content and bind it to a model, in UWP?

Tags: xaml, uwp, model-binding, uwp-xaml

I would like to create a ListView where items have a "hover" and a "selected" state, displaying different content in each state.

There have been some similar question here on StackOverflow, but none helped in my particular case.

Let's say I have a *model*:

```
public class TagFile : BaseBind // A class with INotifyProperyChanged interface
{
    private string path;
    public String Path
    {
        get { return path; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref path, value);
        }
    }

    public void SelectButtonClick() 
    {
        // Do something
    }

    public void HoverButtonClick() 
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

...then I have a main *ViewModel*:

```
public class AppViewModel : BaseBind
{
    public ObservableCollection<TagFile> ItemsList { get; set; }

    // Other things
}
```

... then a *Page*:

```
<Grid>
     <ListView ItemsSource="ItemsList">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:TagFile">
                     <Grid>
                          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                              <RowDefinition/>
                              <RowDefinition/>
                              <RowDefinition/>
                          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                          <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path, mode=OneWay}"/>
                          <Button Content="Select Button" Click="{x:Bind SelectButtonClick}"/> 
                          <Button Content="Hover Button" Click="{x:Bind HoverbuttonClick}"/>
                     </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
     </ListView>
</Grid>
```

I would like to customize ListViewItem Style in order to make the SelectButton appear only when the ListViewItem is selected and the HoverButton only when the cursor is onto it.

I already know that I need to play with ItemTemplate and ItemContainerStyle, but it seems to be more difficult than I tought at the beginning, because I could create a custom style for the ItemContainerStyle in this way (using the IsSelected property from ListViewItem):

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="TestContainerStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Select Button" Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
```

...but in this way:
1) I loose all the default brushes;
2) I don't know how I could bind the SelectButton to the model's command;
3) I would have to find a way for the "hover" state, in order to display the HoverButton;
4) Last, but not least... I would like to include all the customizations in the App.xaml file (or in associated ResourceDictionary files, as I need them across the entire app).

This is it... I have tried various pattern from StackOverflow answers, but my case includes many differnt things (compile binding in App.xaml files, create a "hover" state, using binding in a Style without a DataType, etc.) that are answered here only separately.

I need to... put them all together, and it seems more tricky than I thought, as I said.

Thank you for your help, really appreciate.

EDIT: the behaviour should be like the Groove App list items: some buttons (Play and Remove item) appears only when the the item is selected or in hover state.

Normal state:

[image]

...and Hover/selected state:

[image]

Comment: I think I can partially help. I myself have never tried to do data binding in a style before so hoping we both learn something. Instead of using events you can bind control inputs to viewmodel methods. For just a button click you can use the ICommand interface.  For more advanced input like mouse hover you need to use [Interactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221118/how-to-make-mouseover-event-in-mvvm).

Comment: Also in my (albeit very limited) experience in XAML, doesn't the style template need to contain everything the default one has if you want to keep your brushes etc.?

Comment: @SeanO'Neil, the default style of the ListViewItem contains a ListViewItemPresenter, which was difficult to dealt with... perhaps, it isn't even the correct one, as I was searching for the default one for the ItemContainerStyle, not the ListViewItem Style...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways where you can achieve what you want:

**The first one:** ***I don't prefer it*** as you will need to copy the whole style and embed your item template inside the style. It also doesn't scale if you want to have the same behavior for multiple parts of your app.

You can copy the [ListViewItem style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx) which uses UIElement tree and visual states instead of a ListViewItemPresenter. This way you don't lose default brushes.

Note: look in the above link for the template with `x:Key="ListViewItemExpanded"`.

```
<!-- Style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewItem -->
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="ListViewItemExpanded">
```

Second Note:

> These styles and resources are based on the Windows Software
>   Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 10, Version 1511 (Windows SDK
>   version 10.0.10586.0). Styles and resources from other versions of the
>   SDK might have different values. For design purposes, generic.xaml is
>   available in the (Program Files)\Windows
>   Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.10586.0\Generic
>   folder from a Windows SDK installation.

Now you can use `pointerover` and `selected` states to show and hide different elements.

**Second approach: Using custom control [Recommended]**

Break your problem to two things:

1. You can define IsSelected property in your model/viewmodel for each item, and update that within your select command. Now you can control the first button visibility by binding to IsSelected.
2. Second is the hover part, you create a custom control which expose a dependency property IsPointerOver and you can bind visibility of the 'Hover Button' to it.

Example:

```
public class ExtendedControl : ContentControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPointerOverProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsPointerOver", typeof(bool), typeof(ExtendedControl),
                new PropertyMetadata(false));

        public bool IsPointerOver
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(IsPointerOverProperty);
            protected set => SetValue(IsPointerOverProperty, value);
        }
        protected override void OnPointerEntered(PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPointerEntered(e);
            IsPointerOver = true;
        }
        protected override void OnPointerCanceled(PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPointerCanceled(e);
            IsPointerOver = false;
        }
        protected override void OnPointerExited(PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPointerExited(e);
            IsPointerOver = false;
        }
    }
```

Xaml:

```
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <local:ExtendedControl x:Name="ExtendedControl">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Button Content="Always Visible"/>
                        <Button Content="Only on hover" Visibility="{x:Bind ExtendedControl.IsPointerOver,Mode=OneWay,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </local:ExtendedControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Guess what?   I just figured out this solution by myself today!  XD      Thanks anyway.