# Bind IsMouseOver to ViewModel inside UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

I am creating a custom menu control that changes images (.PNG files) when selected or hovered over using MVVM. Right now the image changes when I select a menu item, but I am struggling to get the hover part to work. Here is the code where I assign the ViewModel to the View:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:MyMenuItem}">
    <view:MyMenuItemControl/>
</DataTemplate>
```

And here is the code I have for my UserControl:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="{Binding DisplayImage}">
        <Image.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding LeftClickCommand}"/>
        </Image.InputBindings>
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsMouseOver" Value="{Binding Path=IsHovered, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

This does not compile because of the IsMouseOver property being read-only, but I can't figure out how to update the ViewModel when this trigger occurs. I'm fairly new to WPF and MVVM, so I apologize if this is a bit ignorant. I searched for about 2 hours and have not been able to find an answer that I can understand and move forward with.

Edit: Here is an Option 2 that doesn't seem to work either. This does compile but does not update the image when I mouse over the item:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="{Binding DisplayImage}">
        <Image.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick"  Command="{Binding LeftClickCommand}"/>
        </Image.InputBindings>
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding DisplayHoverImage}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

**Solution I'm going with:**

```
<Grid>
    <Image>
        <Image.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick"  Command="{Binding LeftClickCommand}"/>
        </Image.InputBindings>
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding DisplayImage}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding DisplayHoverImage}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

Comment: My guess is you don't need triggers, but a Binding using a Converter. You then bind the `Source` property via a Converter that converts the boolean from `IsMouseOver` to an image. Alternatively, you can react to the MouseEnter command: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221118/how-to-make-mouseover-event-in-mvvm

Answer (score -1):

First, define a new control, derived from the control you're trying to use:

```
public class HoverOverImage : Image
{
    public static DependencyProperty MouseOverFrameAreaProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MouseOverFrameArea", typeof(bool), typeof(HoverOverImage)
        , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnMouseOverFrameAreaChanged));
    private bool _mouseOverFrameArea = false;

    public bool MouseOverFrameArea
    {
        get => _mouseOverFrameArea;
        set
        {
            _mouseOverFrameArea = value;
            if (DataContext != null && DataContext.GetType()==typeof(MyViewModel))
                ((MyViewModel)DataContext).MouseOverFrameArea = value;
        }
    }
    private static void OnMouseOverFrameAreaChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((HoverOverImage)d).MouseOverFrameArea = (bool)e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

Then in XAML you should add:

```
<local:HoverOverImage x:Name="framesourceImage" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" Source="{Binding CurrentFrame}">
                    <local:HoverOverImage.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:HoverOverImage}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="MouseOverFrameArea" Value="True"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="MouseOverFrameArea" Value="False"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </local:HoverOverImage.Style>
```