# How to write these particular lines in MVVM WPF(c#)?

Tags: c#, mvvm, mouseenter

.

```
   Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            string name = (sender as Button).Name;
```

I have to convert these two lines to **MVVM** .The following is my code.

**ViewModel.cs** :

```
       public ICommand MouseEnterCommand
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return new RelayCommand(a => this.Executemethod(), p => Canexecutemethod());
                    }
                }
                public bool Canexecutemethod()
                {
                    return true;
                }

                public void Executemethod(){
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            string name = (sender as Button).Name;
switch(name)
            {
case "btn1":
...
case "btn2":
            ...
          }}
```

Where **btn1** and **btn2** are button names.....I have four buttons totally

**View.xaml:**:

```
   <UserControl
    xmlns:interact="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
    ..>
    <Grid>
    <Button Name="btn1">
    <interact:Interaction.Triggers>
    <interact:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
    <interact:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding  Path=DataContext.ZoomInCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
    </interact:EventTrigger>
    </interact:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
    </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

Please help me to write these lines in MVVM..Thanks in advance

Comment: can you check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221118/how-to-make-mouseover-event-in-mvvm

Comment: Please look over my question which I have edited now.....I hope u understand my question @SaravanakumarNatarajan

Comment: You can use interactions and send the button Name  as a command Parameter

Comment: @SaravanakumarNatarajan I am using interactions in View,xaml as I mentioned above...but in ViewModel.cs , I don't know how to write these two lines in MVVM .....Can you please me by editing my code in ViewModel.cs

Comment: How are you having a console window open in a WPF application?

Comment: @Dai Sorry I didn't get u

Comment: Someone please help me......please

Comment: @SaravanakumarNatarajan I am using interactions in View,xaml as I mentioned above...but in ViewModel.cs , I don't know how to write these two lines in MVVM .....Can you please me by editing my code in ViewModel.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you will required `EventToCommandBehavior` which will transfer your event argument of `Click` event to `viewModel`. Like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Behavior that will connect an UI event to a viewmodel Command,
/// allowing the event arguments to be passed as the CommandParameter.
/// </summary>
public class EventToCommandBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    // Event
    public string Event
    {
        get { return ( string ) GetValue( EventProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( EventProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EventProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( nameof( Event ), typeof( string ), typeof( EventToCommandBehavior ),
            new PropertyMetadata( null, OnEventChanged ) );

    // Command
    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return ( ICommand ) GetValue( CommandProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( CommandProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register( nameof( Command ), typeof( ICommand ), typeof( EventToCommandBehavior ), new PropertyMetadata( null ) );

    // PassArguments (default: false)
    public bool PassArguments
    {
        get { return ( bool ) GetValue( PassArgumentsProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( PassArgumentsProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PassArgumentsProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register( nameof( PassArguments ), typeof( bool ), typeof( EventToCommandBehavior ), new PropertyMetadata( false ) );

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AttachHandler( Event ); // initial set
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attaches the handler to the event
    /// </summary>
    private void AttachHandler( string eventName )
    {
        // detach old event
        if ( oldEvent != null )
            oldEvent.RemoveEventHandler( AssociatedObject, handler );

        // attach new event
        if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( eventName ) )
        {
            EventInfo ei = AssociatedObject.GetType().GetEvent( eventName );
            if ( ei != null )
            {
                MethodInfo mi = GetType().GetMethod( nameof( ExecuteCommand ), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic );
                if ( mi != null )
                {
                    handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate( ei.EventHandlerType, this, mi );
                    ei.AddEventHandler( AssociatedObject, handler );
                    oldEvent = ei; // store to detach in case the Event property changes
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(
                        $"Method {nameof( ExecuteCommand )} not found in class {nameof( EventToCommandBehavior )}" );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException( $"The event '{eventName}' was not found on type '{AssociatedObject.GetType().Name}'" );
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OnEventChanged( DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        var beh = ( EventToCommandBehavior ) d;

        if ( beh.AssociatedObject != null ) // is not yet attached at initial load
            beh.AttachHandler( ( string ) e.NewValue );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the Command
    /// </summary>
    // ReSharper disable once UnusedParameter.Local
    private void ExecuteCommand( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        object parameter = PassArguments ? e : null;

        if ( Command != null )
        {
            if ( Command.CanExecute( parameter ) )
                Command.Execute( parameter );
        }
    }

    private Delegate handler;
    private EventInfo oldEvent;
}
```

Use this behavior in your `xaml` for button to pass `RoutedEventArgs` args to your command like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourNameSpace.YourClass">
xmlns:beh="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace.Behaviors"
...
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <Button Margin="2" Content="Button 1" Name="btnButton1">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <beh:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" Event="Click" PassArguments="True" />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Button>
    <Button Margin="2" Content="Button 2" Name="btnButton2">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <beh:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" Event="Click" PassArguments="True" />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Button>

</StackPanel>
```

And Finally create `RelayCommand` like this

```
public RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs> ButtonCommand { get; }

ButtonCommand = new RelayCommand<RoutedEventArgs>( x => Foo(x) );

private void Foo( RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    string buttonName = ( ( System.Windows.FrameworkElement )args.Source ).Name;
    //Your switch statements..
}
```

Likewise you can also attach more events like `MouseEnter` or `MouseLeave`

Comment: Thanks for the response ! @Ankush Madankar

Comment: Is it possible to do this using InvokeCommandAction....Because your answer doesn't seems like it is in MVVM ....Is it in MVVM? ...I actually don't want to use "name=btn1" in view.xaml  thats y. @Ankush Madankar

Comment: @DSPT Yes this appoach is not fully MVVM since your ViewModel should not be knowing about view. But in your case you have single action/command to handle click opertaion from different button hence action identity required in VM. Either you need to create different (3) commands and bind to different button in UI.

Comment: @DSPT Unfortunally you can not pass event argument in command with `InvokeCommandAction` see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205472/mvvm-passing-eventargs-as-command-parameter. Hence I have create different behavior likewise to `InvokeCommandAction` with support of event argument. This will required to identify the action name from UI

Comment: I'm totally confused now...Can anyone edit my code to meet my requirements....Someone please help me!!

Comment: @DSPT Very specific to your question above solution should work. But as part of MVVM I would recommend you to create different `ICommand` for every button displayed on view which have create seperation between your view and vm and let few button events code in xaml.cs file. See this reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421372/why-to-avoid-the-codebehind-in-wpf-mvvm-pattern.. In short little code behind fine which has purely view's operations and not concern about business object. Let me know if you need further help!!

Answer (score 0):

I think, this one work for you

**ViewModel.cs**

```
 public class ViewModel
{
    public ICommand MouseEnterCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(a => this.Executemethod(a), p => Canexecutemethod(p));
        }
    }

    public bool Canexecutemethod(object a)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Executemethod(object p)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

        string name = Convert.ToString(p);

        switch (name)
        {
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

**View.xaml::**

```
<UserControl
    xmlns:interact="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
    ..>
    <Grid>

            <Button Height="25" Width="150">
                <interact:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <interact:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                    <interact:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding  MouseEnterCommand}" CommandParameter="MouseEnter" />
                    </interact:EventTrigger>
                </interact:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Button>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I have edited the switch condition in my question...Please help me to write that type of  switch condition with button names as their case (in MVVM). @Saravanakumar Natarajan

Comment: Thanks in Advance!! @Saravanakumar Natarajan

Comment: @DSPT .You passed button name as CommandParameter="MouseEnter" in the UI and put a break point  in the view model and check the value.

Comment: No....For each button I should have both MouseEnter and MouseLeave events....Is it possible to do that in the way which u specified below? @Saravanakumar Natarajan

Comment: My requirement is ...I should have four buttons and for each button I shoud have button name and two events namely MouseEnter and Mouse Leave....How to achieve this in MVVM....If you know please edit your answer accordingly...Thank you in advance! @Saravanakumar Natarajan

Comment: @DSPT, Each button command parameter you need to mention the command Parameter then you will check work i guess