# How to acces to dependencyProperty within custom Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, custom-controls

i created a custom Canvas that inhirat from Canvas, i declared a new Dependency Property "NewMouseOver" that i want to affect via Setter in Trigger.

```
public class CanvaNetwork : Canvas
{
public CanvaNetwork() { }



public bool NewMouseOver
{
get { return (bool)GetValue(NewMouseOverProperty); }
set { SetValue(NewMouseOverProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty NewMouseOverProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("NewMouseOver", typeof(bool), 
typeof(CanvaNetwork), new PropertyMetadata(false));


}
```

and here is my XAML :

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Node}">
    <local:CanvaNetwork x:Name="ItemCanvas_Node" 
                        NewMouseOver="{Binding MyMouseOver}" 
                        Background="Transparent">

        <Path x:Name="Path_NodeProcess"

                Stroke="Green"
                Fill="Gray"
                Stretch="None"
                Data="{Binding  Path =Geometryform}"
                Visibility="{Binding Path=Visibility}">
        </Path>
        <local:CanvaNetwork.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter  Property="NewMouseOver"  Value="True" />
            </Trigger>
        </local:CanvaNetwork.Triggers>
    </local:CanvaNetwork>
</DataTemplate>
```

hera is my Node Class :

```
Public Node :DependencyObject
{

 public static readonly DependencyProperty MyMouseOverProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyMouseOver", typeof(bool), typeof(NodeProcess), new PropertyMetadata(true,new PropertyChangedCallback(On_MyMouseOver)));

        private static void On_MyMouseOver(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //..some code

        }

        public bool MyMouseOver
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(MyMouseOverProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyMouseOverProperty, value); }
        }



}
```

what i want is :
1-i have DependencyProperty : NewMouseOver (has get and set not like IsMouseOver in the original Canvas Class).
2-acces to NewMouseOver   via Trigger/Setter and change the state of NewMouseOver .
3-via XAML : set a binding betwin : NewMouseOver (in CanvaNetwork)  & MyMouseOver (in Node Class)
4-after that i'll use  On_MyMouseOver (in Node Class) and MyMouseOver to make some stuff.

Comment: The problem is that : NewMouseOver  is not recognized when i want to put : Setter  Property="NewMouseOver"

Comment: Please add the problem into your original question text as opposed to a comment, and format the paragraph with Markdown so it's readable. Good English grammar e.g. capital letters also goes a long way.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I can answer the question about how to update the DependencyProperty in your canvas object.

To test it, I would define an "on changed" method for the dependency property. You can put a breakpoint here to verify that the dependency property is set.

```
class CanvaNetwork : Canvas
{
  public CanvaNetwork ( ) { }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty NewMouseOverProperty
                           = DependencyProperty.Register ( "NewMouseOver",
                                                           typeof (bool),
                                                           typeof (CanvaNetwork),
                                                           new PropertyMetadata (false, OnNewMouseOverChanged)) ;

  public bool NewMouseOver
  {
    get { return (bool)GetValue (NewMouseOverProperty); }
    set { SetValue (NewMouseOverProperty, value); }
  }

  public static void OnNewMouseOverChanged ( DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
  {
  }
}
```

In the DataTemplate, you have to define the triggers within a Style.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Node}">
  <local:CanvaNetwork x:Name="ItemCanvas_Node"
                Background="red" Height="100" Width="100">

    <Path x:Name="Path_NodeProcess"

        Stroke="Green"
        Fill="Gray"
        Stretch="None"
        Data="{Binding  Path =Geometryform}"
        Visibility="{Binding Path=Visibility}">
    </Path>

    <local:CanvaNetwork.Style>
      <Style>
        <Setter  Property="local:CanvaNetwork.NewMouseOver"  Value="False" />
        <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger  Property="Canvas.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter  Property="local:CanvaNetwork.NewMouseOver"  Value="True" />
          </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </local:CanvaNetwork.Style>

  </local:CanvaNetwork>
</DataTemplate>
```

You can only update a property with a trigger, if the default property is set within the style.

For this to work I have removed your attritute **NewMouseOver="{Binding MyMouseOver}"**. From your list, points 1 and 2 work, but removing this attribute means that point 3 does not work.

However, I think that you are probably taking the wrong approach anyway. Wouldn't it be better to hook up the MouseOver event to a command property in your Node class, as described here:

[How to make MouseOver event in MVVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221118/how-to-make-mouseover-event-in-mvvm)

Comment: i used your XAML code and added this : <Setter Property="Cursor"  Value="Cross"/> just to see that the trigger is working, i also add a breakpoint in my "On_MyMouseOver" , the result is : the cursor changed to a cross but no going in "On_MyMouseOver" ?

Comment: Your On_MyMouseOver method is in the Node class. If you define an OnNewMouseOverChanged method in the CanvasNetwork (or CanvaNetwork) via the definition of the DependencyProperty, you should get into that method. I don't think the link to the node class is going to work, which is why I suggested binding the MouseOver event to a command property.

Comment: i added a DataTrigger to make a link between my two DP tne one in the Canvas the other in the Node,"NewMouseOver" becomes the Trigger and i modify via a setter "MyMouseOver" ,the error is that my  MyMouseOver has to be a DP , which it is !